# NSIS - How to copy recursively while excluding files?

Tags: installation, nsis

I need to copy a directory recursively but exclude a couple of directories within it.

The documentation for NSIS says the `File` command takes `/r` and `/x` parameters, but I cannot get them to work together properly.

The structure of my directory containing my .nsi script is:

```
parent-dir
    dir-to-exclude-1
        setup.nsi
    dir-to-copy-1
    dir-to-copy-2
    dir-to-copy-3
    dir-to-exclude-2
```

And I've tried the following, but it's not working for me:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
File /r "..\**" /x "..\dir-to-exclude-1\**" /x "..\dir-to-exclude-2\**"
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:**
I'm getting closer, so now I have:

```
File /r /x \dir-to-exclude-1\*.* /x \dir-to-exclude-2\*.*  ..\*
```

Now it will compile and install all the files, but without excluding the directories I want.  Any guidance for how I can exclude these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a coworker.  Just give the directory names without any *'s:

```
File /r /x dir-to-exclude-1 /x dir-to-exclude-2 /x installer  ..\*
```